# Apache configuration not working properly

Tags: mysql, apache, configuration, server

Hi I'm currently unable to upload sql file greater than 2M on phpmyadmin of my local web server so I edited some config values in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` but values are still not changing, it's still showing the default values after I saved restarted apache. Is there anything wrong or I missed on my configs?

Loaded Configuration File:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Changed values:

```
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```

Comment: Have you restarted the Apache after changing the configuration??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I accidentally added `/` on the very beginning of my php.ini file. Tried to run

`php -i | grep -i "loaded configuration file"`

and shows an error

`PHP:  syntax error, unexpected END_OF_LINE, expecting '=' in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini on line 2`